# Session does not update php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem with my session. 
My test php code:

```
public function updateTable() {
    $data = $this->getData();
    $json_data = array(
        "recordsTotal"      => intval($data['totalData']),
        "recordsFiltered"   => intval($data['totalFiltered']),
        "data"              => $data['listItem']
    );

    // set session
    $this->session->set_userdata('listSelectedId',$data['listSelectedId']);
    var_dump($_SESSION['listSelectedId']);
    echo json_encode($json_data);
}

public function test() {
   var_dump($_SESSION['listSelectedId']);
}
```

My jquery ajax code when click a button:

```
// call updateTable function
dataTable.ajax.reload();


$.ajax({
    url: 'MyClass/test',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(){
    }
});
```

After `dataTable.ajax.reload();`

the result is an array `[0 => 1]`, but The result of ajax test is an empty array.

When I click button the second times, add more `id` to session `listSelectedId`, `dataTable.ajax.reload();` returns `[0 => 1, 1 => 2]` and The result of ajax test is `[0 => 1]`.

I dont know why same session in 2 function, but different `var_dump` value.

Comment: how do you call your class methods in test.php file?

Comment: did you use `session_start();` on top of your ajax file?

Comment: There's barely enough information to go with here. You give us two functions but no indication on how or where you;re calling them and also no idea on whether you're starting the session at all.

Comment: I have updated my question, I use CI Framework

Comment: My guess would be that `dataTable.ajax.reload` itself is asynchronous, and therefor code execution does not “wait”, but your own AJAX call is made immediately, before the first request is even finished ...

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter, use the [session library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: The PHP snippet you've shown us will not generate parseable JSON, and is not complete, the javascript code you've shown us discards the output of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, You must refresh php script when you set session up. Otherwise, the value will be the old one.